# How can I verify that a date range includes a weekend?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a date range that comes from MySQL, for example:
*2016-01-05 to 2016-01-10*. I would like to check if both Saturday and Sunday are inside that date-range, not necessarily consecutive. So far I have found:

```
function isWeekend($date) {
    return (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6);
}
```

So I would have to loop for every single day in the range to see if it's a weekend day.

Are there any better approaches?

Comment: Are the dates always shorter than 7 days?

Comment: @Ares sometimes, the dates can be any length of days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to loop over all the days. You just need to know the length of the date range and the first day's day of the week.

Assuming you have two `DateTime` objects:

```
$start = new DateTime('2016-01-05');
$end = new DateTime('2016-01-10');
```

You can determine if a Saturday and Sunday are contained in the date range by checking if the length of the range plus the numeric weekday of the start date is greater than 6.

```
function includes_weekend (DateTime $start, DateTime $end) {
    return $start->diff($end)->format('%a') + $start->format('w') > 6;
}
```

`format('%a')` returns the total number of days in the `DateInterval` returned by `diff`,  and `format('w')` returns the numeric day of the week (Sunday = 0).

Answer (score 0):

You would not have to check every single day.

I'll try to explain this with just plain English:

First, check if it starts on a weekend. If it does, you're already done. If the date span is more than 6 days, then you can immediately assume that yes, a weekend day is included. If it's 5 days, then the first day *has* to be on a Monday, otherwise it contains a weekend day. If it's four, it *has* to be on a Tuesday... and so on.

Comment: thank you for your reply but your logic is flawed. If my date range starts on Saturday and ends in Tuesday, the first day will _never_ be Monday.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have clarified. Always check the first day to see if it's a weekend. That should eliminate the edge case.